# How to keep rewrite_rule without flushing each time?

Tags: url-rewriting

I have some custom products that need to be loaded into a specific url structure, the code is the following:

```
foreach ($products as $prod) {
  $prod_obj = wc_get_product($prod->ID);
  
  $categories = wp_get_post_terms($prod->ID, 'product_cat');
  if (empty($categories) && is_wp_error($categories)) continue;
  
  $custom_slug = get_field('custom_slug', $prod->ID);

  add_rewrite_rule(
    "^cpo/watches/$custom_slug/?$",
    'index.php?post_type=product&p=' . $prod->ID . '&model=$matches[1]&size=$matches[2]&reference=$matches[3]',
    'top'
  );
}
```

the code above iterate over the `$products` and then add a rewrite rule that allow to show each product under a custom permalink using an acf field, so the final structure will look like this: `https://example.com/cpo/watches/foo-456-hello-world`.

Now the problem's that sometimes when I visit the url above I will get 404, so I have to flush the permalink in backend to make it working, and this is a pain.
So a temporary workaround I did this:

```
add_action('template_redirect', function () {
  if (is_404()) {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
  }
});
```

The code above check if the current page is in `404` and then refresh the rules automatically, in this way if the page is refreshed the custom product is visible.
Even though this solution "fix" the manual permalink refresh, I would like to avoid to show a 404 page to the final user, is there a way to keep the rewrite rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My usual trick to a) flush as required but b) not flush on *every page load* is to use an option to determine if the rewrites have changed, and flush only if they have indeed changed.

Something like this:

```
add_action( 'wp', 'wpse_421338_maybe_flush_rewrites' );
function wpse_421388_maybe_flush_rewrites() {
    $rewrite_obj = new WP_Rewrite();
    $rewrites    = $rewrite_obj->wp_rewrite_rules();
    // Compare the current state of the rewrites to the last stored state.
    $current_state = md5( json_encode( $rewrites ) );
    $stored_state  = get_option( 'wpse_421338_rewrite_state', '' );
    if ( $current_state !== $stored_state ) {
        // If things have changed, flush the rewrites...
        flush_rewrite_rules();
        // ...and store the new state.
        update_option( 'wpse_421338_rewrite_state', $current_state );
    }
}
```

...might work.

Note that this code is *untested* and should not be used in production until you're sure it works.

### References

- [`WP_Rewrite::wp_rewrite_rules()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rewrite/wp_rewrite_rules/)

Comment: nice solution, thanks